# Quebrar String para Array

Tags: java, array

Estou com um retorno de uma `string` vinda da API REST da seguinte forma:

```
string bancos = ["BRADESCO", "ITAU", "SANTANDER"];
```

Só que eu quero fazer com que essa string seja um array para que eu faça uma iteração com os retornos.

**Como faço pra transformar essa string em um array ?**

Comment: Poderia mostrar uma copia dessa parte do json?
Porque da forma que está não é valida a sintaxe.

Comment: @vladwoguer o retorno é uma string exatamente com esse  resultado `["BRADESCO", "ITAU", "SANTANDER"]` e quero transforma isso em um array

Comment: No caso você tem então o equivalente a fazer: ```String bancos = "[\"BRADESCO\", \"ITAU\", \"SANTANDER\"]";```

Comment: @vladwoguer Não, pela segunda vez como eu disse é EXATAMENTE isso `String bancos = "["BRADESCO", "ITAU", "SANTANDER"]"`

Comment: Desculpe achei que era um Json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na linha abaixo veja como fazer isso usando Gson:

```
String[] anotherStr = gson.fromJson("[\"abc\"]", String[].class);
```

Em tempo, a linha acima foi extraída de https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Primitives-Examples

Neste caso é assumido que a sequência recebida é uma serialização válida de um array de strings em Json.